# What ways are there to improve the Chaos DoT of viper strike?

Tags: path-of-exile

Just what the question states. Normally, I only want to know if there are any nodes/passives that boost [Chaos Damage](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102802/what-is-chaos-damage-in-path-of-exile), and whether or not it is improved by Spell Damage nodes, but might as well make it a broad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, [the wiki doesn't list any passive to improve Chaos damage type](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Damage_Types) (while there are options for physical and elemental damage).  There's only a line about a notable passive, but it doesn't really *increase* chaos damage:

> The Notable Passive [Adders Touch](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/21343/page/1) allows you to poison enemies with Critical Strikes with Daggers. Deals chaos damage equal to 10% of the damage done by the hit per second, for 2 seconds.

There's also [a conversation in the official forums entitled "Increasing Poison (Chaos) Damage?"](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/27802/highlight/), but to be short, there are no passives mentioned: the best way remains to level up the gem.

In another chaos damage conversation, I've found [this answer (given on September 7, 2012)](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/49249/highlight/#p633426):

> **Added Chaos Damage support**
>
> - +Chaos Damage uniques are improved by +attack speed
> - +X% spell damage increases chaos damage done by a spell
> - +Skill duration improves poison cloud's poison damage Adder's Touch has scaling chaos damage

Comment: So... Adder's Touch scales with 10% of the DPS with the stuff that i have equipped when throwing it? (Be it dual wielding)

Comment: 10% (per second, for 2 seconds) of the *inflicted* damage.

Comment: Aah... so if i crit for 200 with say, dual strike, it will deal 20 damage 2 times with AT?

Comment: That's how I understand it, but I'm not playing that skill so I cannot confirm, sorry.